# android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found in android studio

Tags: android

in last week  compile my program successful but now  I can't build my project because of this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfMOP.jpg)

i dont want change compileSdkVersion to 28 
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Try to invalidate the cache and restart android studio.

Answer (score 0):

> in last week compile my program successful but now I can't build my project because of this error

You are now using some version of some dependency that requires a `compileSdkVersion` of 28 or higher.

> i dont want change compileSdkVersion to 28

Change it anyway. You need to keep your dependencies up to date, to receive bug fixes. The developers of those dependencies keep their `compileSdkVersion` up to date, which sometimes requires users of those dependencies up to date.

Alternatively, you can use version control, backups, or something to try to identify what you changed recently in the `dependencies` closure of your module's `build.gradle` file, then switch back to the older version. This is not a suitable long-term solution.